# Windows 10 increase mouse speed above 100%

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, lenovo-vantage

I've got a notebook with 4k display. Unfortunately, now it takes at least two full diagonals on the trackpoint to move the mouse from one corner of the screen to the other diagonal. I already set the mouse courser speed to the highest value, but it is by far not enough. Is there any way to increase the mouse speed or modify the maximum value in the mouse dialoge. It is a Lenovo X1 Yoga.

Comment: I do not think you can make the mouse move faster than the settings allow. Have you installed the latest UNAV driver? Also try an external mouse to see if that works better

Comment: I don't want tu use an external mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open registry editor. Then find the registry key `HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse`. Now set `MouseThreshold1` and `MouseThreshold2` values to 0. Then set `MouseSpeed` to 2 (Quadraple current speed) or 1 (Double current speed). `MouseSpeed` value can't be more than 2. Then reboot. Mouse will now be more faster.

Comment: It is not fast enough :-(

Comment: Did you try a new driver?  The registry setting above just makes current speed faster but not faster than it will go.

Comment: Yes @John I also updated mouse driver

Answer (score 0):

This program will help you edit the mouse speed curve.

But hopefully you've already found a solution.

https://www.esreality.com/post/2363191/custom-mouse-accel-program-for-windows/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).